# Remove the white space between the item label and the equations

Tags: math-mode, equations

Here is a question. I want to know how to remove the white space  between the item label and the equations?  For example, I want to remove the blank between the number 1 and the equation f(X)=...

The code and picture are as follows[image]

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{eqnarray*}   
f(X)&=& AD+SF SF SDF+DFDF FA \\
&+&SADSADDDDDDDDDDDA D+D DADS AD
\end{eqnarray*}

\item
\begin{equation*}
G(X)=ADSA DASD SAD ASD ASD
\end{equation*}

\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Two more existing questions that offer several (and possibly better) useful approaches: [Vertical alignment of `align*` in `enumerate`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9394) and [Equations inside `enumerate` aligned on item's number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58141)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to `tex.SE`... Hope the below codes may helps you:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\mathitem{\item\leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\abovedisplayskip\relax}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\mathitem 
\begin{align*}   
f(X)&= AD+SF SF SDF+DFDF FA \\
&\quad+ SADSADDDDDDDDDDDA D+D DADS AD
\end{align*}


\mathitem
\begin{equation*}
G(X)=ADSA DASD SAD ASD ASD
\end{equation*}

\item This is for test
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Note that please try to avoid `eqnarray` which is little bit older, use `amsmath` environments like `align, gather`, etc. Also hope your operator alignment was wrong, `+` sign should be quad indent with `=`

PS: Big thanks to `Bernard` who already gave this suggestion, refer [Remove white line after \item in enumerate and before display math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309886/remove-white-line-after-item-in-enumerate-and-before-display-math)

Comment: Ingenious! (+1)

Comment: @Bernard Thanks... :-D

Comment: I try this, it looks excellent. Many thanks.  Also, thanks a lot for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on `\makebox[\linewidth]`  and `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
\begin{enumerate}
\item \makebox[\linewidth]{$\displaystyle\begin{aligned}[t]
f(X)={} &AD+SF SF SDF+DFDF FA \\
&+SADSADDDDDDDDDDDA D+D DADS AD
\end{aligned}$}
\item \makebox[\linewidth]{$\displaystyle G(X)=ADSA DASD SAD ASD ASD$}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]